# В заданном тексте в конце каждого слова добавить первый символ этого слова

Tags: java, eclipse

Нужно **выполнить** вот такое **задание** с помощью **Java**:

**"В заданном тексте в конце каждого слова добавить первый символ этого слова."**

Как я понимаю единственным решением будет каким то образом преобразовать строку в массив символов и работать уже с ним? Тогда как преобразовать строку в массив символов? Или как брать каждый символ, отдельно в цикле?

---

Заранее *спасибо за помощь*.

Comment: я совсем начинающий в программировании (не знаю даже методов работы со строками, а те что нашел пока не могу придумать как использовать для алгоритма). Как я понимаю единственным решением будет каким то образом преобразовать строку в массив символов и работать уже с ним?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: @onlyonepiece, в таком случае возьмите книгу Head First Java и читайте.

Comment: можете просто запомнить первый символ, потом искать последовательно один из символов разделителей строк в тексте, при нахождении вставлять перед ним запомненный и запоминать следующий. это чтобы не преобразовывать в массивы, самый простой способ

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "В заданном тексте в конце каждого слова добавить первый символ этого слова.";

    //разделяю на фрагменты
    LinkedList<StringBuilder> ll = new LinkedList<StringBuilder>();
    for(int fIndex = 0, sIndex;;){
        sIndex = text.indexOf(" ", fIndex);
        if (sIndex==-1) {
            ll.add(new StringBuilder(text.substring(fIndex, text.length())));
            break;
        }
        ll.add(new StringBuilder(text.substring(fIndex, sIndex)));
        fIndex = sIndex+1;
    }

    //отделяю знаки припинания
    for(int i = 0;i<ll.size();i++){
        StringBuilder t = ll.get(i);

        if (t.toString().equals(" ")) continue;

        //отделяю начало
        StringBuilder fCh = new StringBuilder(1);
        while(true){
            char ch = t.charAt(0);
            if (isLetter(ch)) break;
            fCh.append(ch);
            t.deleteCharAt(0);
        }

        //отделяю конец
        StringBuilder lCh = new StringBuilder(1);
        while(true){
            char ch = t.charAt(t.length()-1);
            if (isLetter(ch)) break;
            lCh.append(ch);
            t.deleteCharAt(t.length()-1);
        }

        //добавляю начало в структуру
        if (fCh.length()>0){
            ll.add(i, fCh);
            i++;
        }

        //выполняю твое задание
        t.insert(t.length(), t.charAt(0));
        //изменяю строку в структуре
        ll.set(i, t);

        //добавляю конец в структуру
        if (lCh.length()>0){
            ll.add(i+1, lCh);
            i++;
        }
    }

    //собираю строку
    StringBuilder sol = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    while(true){
        try{
            sol.append(ll.removeFirst());
            sol.append(' ');
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            sol.deleteCharAt(sol.length()-1);
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sol.toString());
```

если не нужно управлять списком символов, `Character.isLetter(ch)` подойдет лучше
у меня метод isLetter(char ch) реализован так:

```
private boolean isLetter(char ch){
    if ((ch>'а')&&(ch<'я'))return true;
    if ((ch>'А')&&(ch<'Я'))return true;
    if ((ch>'a')&&(ch<'z'))return true;
    if ((ch>'A')&&(ch<'Z'))return true;
    return false;
}
```